# commons-logging to debug in Cassandra

Tags: debugging, cassandra

**EDIT:**
The accepted answer is due to the original question being for C* 2.2. Since then I've switched to working on the trunk version of the code, and I've been able to debug it with Intellij IDEA with no problem whatsoever.

**Original Question:**

Looking at the [HowToDebug](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HowToDebug) page from the Cassandra wiki, point 4.2 says to add the commons-logging jar to the new project used for debugging. However, I don't find this in the build folder of the Cassandra project. I guess this jar has been replaced by another in a version after the time the article was written. Nowadays to debug, which jars to I need to add?

Same question for build/lib/jars/pig-*.jar, as I don't see this jar in the respective folder as well.

I'm working on the code of Cassandra 2.2.

**EDIT:**
Using the solution below, I got the following output right after starting the debugger:

```
WARN  16:53:19 Only 40913 MB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
WARN  16:53:19 Only 40913 MB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
WARN  16:53:19 jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  16:53:19 jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  16:53:19 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
WARN  16:53:19 JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
ERROR 16:53:19 cassandra.jmx.local.port missing from cassandra-env.sh, unable to start local JMX service.
ERROR 16:53:19 cassandra.jmx.local.port missing from cassandra-env.sh, unable to start local JMX service.
WARN  16:53:20 Directory build/test/cassandra/data doesn't exist
WARN  16:53:20 Directory build/test/cassandra/data doesn't exist
WARN  16:53:20 Directory build/test/cassandra/commitlog doesn't exist
WARN  16:53:20 Directory build/test/cassandra/commitlog doesn't exist
WARN  16:53:20 Directory build/test/cassandra/saved_caches doesn't exist
WARN  16:53:20 Directory build/test/cassandra/saved_caches doesn't exist
WARN  16:53:22 No host ID found, created d47c6743-a52c-4298-9f6d-3588a7765888 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
WARN  16:53:22 No host ID found, created d47c6743-a52c-4298-9f6d-3588a7765888 (Note: This should happen exactly once per node).
WARN  16:53:22 Generated random token [cd5af2b96149d21ba54a6b35d8d4a05d]. Random tokens will result in an unbalanced ring; see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations
WARN  16:53:22 Generated random token [cd5af2b96149d21ba54a6b35d8d4a05d]. Random tokens will result in an unbalanced ring; see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations
```

Is this expected? I suppose I can ignore the first message regarding the available disc space, but what about the other ones? Is the duplicated messages a normal thing as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably be more successful by connecting to Cassandra running as an external process instead of starting Cassandra from Eclipse. I'd recommend to use [ccm](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm) to setup a local cluster with debug ports enabled. Afterwards you can connect to any of the started node from Eclipse and start debugging.

1. Clone Cassandra into working directory and build jar file if not already done
2. Use ccm to create new empty cluster based on sources from git: `ccm create 2.2-1n --install-dir=/path/to/build/sources/cassandra-2.2`
3. Add node to cluster: `ccm add -s -r 9881 -j 8001 -i 127.0.0.1 node1` (-r will specify remote debug port, -j JMX port)
4. Start cluster: `ccm start`
5. Connect from eclipse: `Run -> Debug configurations -> Remote Java Application -> Right click and select "Add" -> Enter -r port value in connection settings`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've tried your method, but I don't think I got it quite right... Can you please check the EDIT in my question?

Comment: Where did you find the logging output?